# strcpy() only copying one string to a struct, but not the other

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, strcpy

I'll cut it down to the bare basics, as the rest of the code is unnecessary. It's a basic text adventure program.

```
// defines numeric values for each room
typedef enum {
    KITCHEN,
    PANTRY,
    HALLWAY_1,
    HALLWAY_2,
    TROLLS_DOMAIN,
    EMPTY_ROOM_1,
    EMPTY_ROOM_2,
    EXIT,
    NO_ROOM
} en_rooms;

// defines a struct type to store room data
typedef struct room{
    char name[50];
    char desc[50]; // description
} Room;

// fills the array r with info on each room.
void room_setup(Room *r){
    strcpy(r[KITCHEN].name, "Kitchen");
    strcpy(r[KITCHEN].desc, "This is the kitchen.");
}

int main(void){
    ...

    Room rooms[10];
    room_setup(rooms); // fill rooms array with info
    en_rooms currentRoom = KITCHEN; // set the starting room to the kitchen

    // main game loop
    while(1){

        ...

        // print room name + description
        printf("-- %s --\n", rooms[currentRoom].name);
        printf("%s\n", rooms[currentRoom].desc);

        ...
    }
}
```

For whatever reason, the output is this:

```
-- rP@ --
This is the kitchen.
```

Can anyone help me work out why strcpy() will copy the rooms description, but not it's name properly?

Comment: My guess is that something is clobbering the name between setup and print.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. It's likely the problem is in code you have not shown.

Comment: I don't why but your code work as expected http://ideone.com/zFX5z5